# do shell script with awk fails in AppleScript, but same awk command works in Terminal

Tags: shell, awk, applescript, zsh

Making a shell script work in AppleScript.

The following works in Terminal:

```
awk -F\" '/kMDItemTextContent/{print $2}' /Users/john/Desktop/PDFTags/mdimport.txt
```

But that same line, with `do shell script`, throws an error in Script Editor.

```
do shell script "awk -F\" '/kMDItemTextContent/{print $2}' /Users/john/Desktop/PDFTags/mdimport.txt"
```

This is from the Replies in Script Editor:

```
tell current application do shell script "awk -F\" '/kMDItemTextContent/{print $2}' /Users/john/Desktop/PDFTags/mdimport.txt"
--> error "sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `\"' sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file" number 2
```

For reference, here is the context of mdimport.txt

```
Imported '/Users/John/Desktop/PDFTags/Untitled.txt' of type 'public.plain-text' with plugIn /System/Library/Spotlight/RichText.mdimporter. 32 attributes returned {
    ":EA:_kMDItemUserTags" =     (
    );
    ":EA:kMDItemLastUsedDate" = "2020-11-07 08:17:13 +0000";
    ":MD:DeviceId" = 16777227;
    ":MD:kMDItemPath" = "/Users/john/Desktop/PDFTags/Untitled.txt";
    "_kMDItemContentChangeDate" = "2020-11-05 23:24:57 +0000";
    "_kMDItemCreationDate" = "2020-11-05 22:34:36 +0000";
    "_kMDItemCreatorCode" = 0;
    "_kMDItemDisplayNameWithExtensions" =     {
        "" = "Untitled.txt";
    };
    "_kMDItemFileName" = "Untitled.txt";
    "_kMDItemFinderFlags" = 16;
    "_kMDItemFinderLabel" = 0;
    "_kMDItemFromImporter" = 1;
    "_kMDItemIsExtensionHidden" = 1;
    "_kMDItemIsFromImporter" = 1;
    "_kMDItemLocked" = 1;
    "_kMDItemOwnerGroupID" = 20;
    "_kMDItemOwnerUserID" = 501;
    "_kMDItemTextEncodingHint" = 134217984;
    "_kMDItemTypeCode" = 0;
    "com_apple_metadata_modtime" = "626311497.290109";
    kMDItemAlternateNames =     (
        "Untitled.txt"
    );
    kMDItemContentCreationDate = "2020-11-05 22:34:36 +0000";
    kMDItemContentModificationDate = "2020-11-05 23:24:57 +0000";
    kMDItemContentType = "public.plain-text";
    kMDItemContentTypeTree =     (
        "public.plain-text",
        "public.text",
        "public.data",
        "public.item",
        "public.content"
    );
    kMDItemDateAdded = "2020-11-07 08:56:45 +0000";
    kMDItemDisplayName =     {
        "" = Untitled;
    };
    kMDItemDocumentIdentifier = 27837;
    kMDItemKind =     {
        "" = NSStringPboardType;
        ar = "\U0645\U0633\U062a\U0646\U062f \U0646\U0635\U064a \U0639\U0627\U062f\U064a";
        ca = "Document de text sense format";
        cs = "Prost\U00fd textov\U00fd dokument";
        da = "Alm. tekstdokument";
        de = "Reines Textdokument";
        el = "\U0388\U03b3\U03b3\U03c1\U03b1\U03c6\U03bf \U03b1\U03c0\U03bb\U03bf\U03cd \U03ba\U03b5\U03b9\U03bc\U03ad\U03bd\U03bf\U03c5";
        en = "Plain Text Document";
        "en_AU" = "Plain Text Document";
        "en_GB" = "Plain Text Document";
        es = "Documento de texto sin formato";
        "es_419" = "Documento de texto sin formato";
        fi = "Pelkk\U00e4 teksti -dokumentti";
        fr = "Document format texte";
        "fr_CA" = "Document format texte";
        he = "\U05de\U05e1\U05de\U05da \U05de\U05dc\U05dc \U05e4\U05e9\U05d5\U05d8";
        hi = "\U092a\U094d\U0932\U0947\U0928 \U091f\U0947\U0915\U094d\U0938\U094d\U091f \U0926\U0938\U094d\U0924\U093e\U0935\U0947\U091c\U093c";
        hr = "Dokument obi\U010dnog teksta";
        hu = "Sima sz\U00f6veges dokumentum";
        id = "Dokumen Teks Biasa";
        it = "Documento di solo testo";
        ja = "\U6a19\U6e96\U30c6\U30ad\U30b9\U30c8\U66f8\U985e";
        ko = "\Uc77c\Ubc18 \Ud14d\Uc2a4\Ud2b8 \Ubb38\Uc11c";
        ms = "Dokumen Teks Biasa";
        nl = "Platte-tekstdocument";
        no = "Dokument med ren tekst";
        pl = "dokument tekstowy (zwyk\U0142y)";
        pt = "Documento de Texto Simples";
        "pt_PT" = "Documento de texto simples";
        ro = "Document text simplu";
        ru = "\U0414\U043e\U043a\U0443\U043c\U0435\U043d\U0442 \U043f\U0440\U043e\U0441\U0442\U043e\U0433\U043e \U0442\U0435\U043a\U0441\U0442\U0430";
        sk = "Dokument s\U00a0oby\U010dajn\U00fdm textom";
        sv = "Rent textdokument";
        th = "\U0e40\U0e2d\U0e01\U0e2a\U0e32\U0e23\U0e02\U0e49\U0e2d\U0e04\U0e27\U0e32\U0e21\U0e18\U0e23\U0e23\U0e21\U0e14\U0e32";
        tr = "D\U00fcz Metin Belgesi";
        uk = "\U0414\U043e\U043a\U0443\U043c\U0435\U043d\U0442 \U043f\U0440\U043e\U0441\U0442\U043e\U0433\U043e \U0442\U0435\U043a\U0441\U0442\U0443";
        vi = "T\U00e0i li\U1ec7u v\U0103n b\U1ea3n thu\U1ea7n t\U00fay";
        "zh_CN" = "\U7eaf\U6587\U672c\U6587\U7a3f";
        "zh_HK" = "\U7d14\U6587\U5b57\U6587\U4ef6";
        "zh_TW" = "\U7d14\U6587\U5b57\U6587\U4ef6";
    };
    kMDItemLogicalSize = 345;
    kMDItemPhysicalSize = 4096;
    kMDItemTextContent = "Here are the text file contents that was used to test the routine.\n\nHash Tag Test Document\n\n#HashTag1 this is the first hash tag.\n#HashTag2 this is the second hash tag.\n\nThe following hash tag is inside and at the end of a paragraph:
#HashTag3\n\nThe next hash tag #HashTag4 is in the middle of a paragraph.\n\n#HashTag5\n#asdfasdfasdfasdfasfdasdfasd"; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at a portion of the error message:

> unexpected EOF while looking for matching `\"'

It is referring to the *field separator* assigned by: `-F`

You need to, in this case, both *single-quote* and *escape* the single *double-quote*.

```
do shell script "awk -F'\"' '/kMDItemTextContent/{print $2}' /Users/john/Desktop/PDFTags/mdimport.txt"
```

**Result:**

> "Here are the text file contents that was used to test the
> routine.\n\nHash Tag Test Document\n\n#HashTag1 this is the first
> hash tag.\n#HashTag2 this is the second hash tag.\n\nThe following
> hash tag is inside and at the end of a paragraph:"

Comment: Also, since the whole thing is now in double quotes, the inner single quotes for the awk body are just plain characters, so the awk variable `$2` will need to be escaped.

Comment: @glenn jackman, There does not need to be any additional  escaping in what I posted as it works as is! The outer _double-quotes_ of the `do shell script` _command_ are not passed to the _shell_. What's passed is, e.g., `awk -F'\"' '/kMDItemTextContent/{print $2}' /Users/john/Desktop/PDFTags/mdimport.txt` and this gets the exact same results if pasted into **Terminal** and executed, or run by the `do shell script` _command_.